# How to create an autoincrement ID field

Tags: go, struct, auto-increment

I have a set of employees defined in a JSON-file:

```golang
type PrimitiveEmployee struct {
    PrimitiveID     string   `xml:"ID,attr"`
    ContractID      []string `xml:"ContractID"`
}
```

Both `ID` and `ContractID` is letters, but they are not necessarily given continuous sequence of letters. For instance, there might exist an employee with *PrimitiveID=A* and another with *PrimitiveID=C*, but not an employee with *PrimitiveID=B*.

I want to convert this data into:

```golang
type Employee struct {
    ID              int
    PrimitiveID     string
    Contracts       []Contract
}
```

The thing is, I want the the employee-ID to start at 0 and increment with one for each time the struct is initialized. Sort of like a an autoincrement ID in a database or iota in a enum.

The employee with *PrimitiveID=A* will then automatically be created with *ID=0*, while the employee with *PrimitiveID=C* will get *ID=1*.

I just cant figure out how to solve this in a struct.

Greatly appreciate any help or pointers here.

Comment: Have a global variable containing the counter, and in a function which costructs instances of your `Employee`-s, read that variable and increment it afterwards. Supposedly you will be better served by `sync/atomic.AddInt*` functions (as otherwise your code cannot be used by concurrently running goroutines). To answer maybe unasked question, no, you cannot have what you want to work somehow "automagically" as Go does not have "constructors".

Comment: If you're stroing a bunch of Employee structs in memory, you could put them in an array and use their offsets for their IDs.  This guarantees they're unique and conceptually automatically increments when you append to the array.  UUID would be another option.  One of the nice things about using a uuid, is that they're not sequential and so employee numbers can be guessed pretty easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom type to manage the unique incrementing ID:

```
type autoInc struct {
    sync.Mutex // ensures autoInc is goroutine-safe
    id int
}

func (a *autoInc) ID() (id int) {
    a.Lock()
    defer a.Unlock()

    id = a.id
    a.id++
    return
}
```

So you can use it in targeted places or at the package level:

```
var ai autoInc // global instance
```

You can then create "constructor" functions to leverage this:

```
func NewEmployee() *Employee {
    return &Employee{
        ID: ai.ID(),
    }
}
```

Marshaling JSON data to `Employee` can then be performed and the ID will be preserved - provided the JSON data does not container an `ID` tag.

https://play.golang.org/p/0iTaQSzTPZ_j